# Building PySide for Android error: 'getWrapperForQObject' is not a member of 'PySide'

Tags: android, qt, ubuntu, build, pyside

I am following the [PySide for Android guide](http://wiki.qt.io/PySide_for_Android_guide) under Xubuntu 14.04 for which I ran the following commands:

```
wget http://files.kde.org/necessitas/installer/release/linux-online-necessitas-alpha4-sdk-installer
chmod u+x linux-online-necessitas-alpha4-sdk-installer
sudo apt-get install build-essential openjdk-7-jdk libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 cmake git shiboken
./linux-online-necessitas-alpha4-sdk-installer

git clone https://github.com/M4rtinK/android-pyside-build-scripts.git
cd android-pyside-build-scripts
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1.1 libxslt1-dev
./build.sh
```

Starting the `./build.sh` script prints the following lines before starting to build Shiboken:

```
= Combined Shiboken & PySide Android build script
* Shiboken will be built first, followed by PySide *
= PySide android build script =
* cleaning up previous build (both Shiboken & PySide) *
* Important paths: *
* Python dir: /home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/android_python
* Python include dirs: /home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/android_python/include/python2.7
* Python libraries: /home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/android_python/lib
* configuring Shiboken for build *
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/android to use this system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /home/friendfx/necessitas/Android/Qt/482/armeabi/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.2", minimum required is "4.5.0") 
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found suitable version "2.9.1", minimum required is "2.6.32") 
-- Found LibXslt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so (found suitable version "1.1.28", minimum required is "1.1.19") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/shiboken-build
* Press any key to start the Shiboken build *
```

The Shiboken build completed successfully, then the PySide build step is initialised like so:

```
= PySide Android build script =
* cleaning up previous PySide build *
* Important variables & paths: *
* LDFLAGS: --sysroot /home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -L/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/android_python/lib -nostdlib -shared -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-shared,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/home/friendfx/necessitas/Android/Qt/482/armeabi//lib -lQtCore -lpython2.7 -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lgcc -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -L/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/stage/lib/libshiboken.so -lshiboken -lQtCore
#####
* CXXFLAGS: -I/home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe --sysroot /home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm -L/home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi -I/home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include -I/home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include -I/home/friendfx/necessitas/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -I/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/stage/include/shiboken -I/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/android_python/include -L/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/stage/lib -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-strict-aliasing -rdynamic
* Python dir: /home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/android_python
* configuring PySide for build *
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/android to use this system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /home/friendfx/necessitas/Android/Qt/482/armeabi/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.2", minimum required is "4.5.0") 
-- Detected OS: android
-- PySide will be generated using the protected hack!
-- Checking for QAbstractPageSetupDialog in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QAbstractPrintDialog in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QGtkStyle in QtGui -- not found
-- Checking for QPageSetupDialog in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QPrintDialog in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QPrintEngine in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QPrintPreviewDialog in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QPrintPreviewWidget in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QPrinter in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QPrinterInfo in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QSessionManager in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QSizeGrip in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QSystemTrayIcon in QtGui -- found
-- Checking for QMacStyle in QtGui -- not found
-- Checking for QSslCertificate in QtNetwork -- found
-- Checking for QSslCipher in QtNetwork -- found
-- Checking for QSslConfiguration in QtNetwork -- found
-- Checking for QSslError in QtNetwork -- found
-- Checking for QSslKey in QtNetwork -- found
-- Checking for QSslSocket in QtNetwork -- found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build
* fixing borked link paths in PySide *
fixing libpyside link
fixing libshiboken link
fixing Python links
fixing Qt links
fixing done
* Press any key to start the PySide build *
```

The build runs for a bit but then (at about 3%), fails with the following lines:

```
Building CXX object PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstractfileenginehandler_wrapper.cpp.obj
Building CXX object PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstractfileengineiterator_wrapper.cpp.obj
Building CXX object PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel_wrapper.cpp.obj
/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build/PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp: In function 'PyObject* QAbstractEventDispatcher_PTR_CppToPython_QAbstractEventDispatcher(const void*)':
/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build/PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp:1476: error: 'getWrapperForQObject' is not a member of 'PySide'
make[2]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build/PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel_wrapper.cpp: In function 'PyObject* QAbstractItemModel_PTR_CppToPython_QAbstractItemModel(const void*)':
/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build/PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel_wrapper.cpp:5154: error: 'getWrapperForQObject' is not a member of 'PySide'
make[2]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel_wrapper.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[  3%] Built target pyside
[  3%] Building CXX object PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp.obj
/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build/PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp: In function 'PyObject* QAbstractEventDispatcher_PTR_CppToPython_QAbstractEventDispatcher(const void*)':
/home/friendfx/android-pyside-build-scripts/pyside-build/PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp:1476: error: 'getWrapperForQObject' is not a member of 'PySide'
make[2]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I googled for errors related to `getWrapperForQObject` not being a member of PySide but couldn't find anything helpful, does anyone have a clue what might be the problem I have run into?

Comment: I would also contact the PySide mailinglist: http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/pyside